# Scroll algorithm -- improving fetch and display of data

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, canvas, virtualscroll

I would like to set out somewhat of a theoretical problem.

Suppose that I have an infinite scroll, implemented something like as described here: https://medium.com/frontend-journeys/how-virtual-infinite-scrolling-works-239f7ee5aa58. There's nothing fancy to it, suffice it to say that it is a table of data, say NxN, and the user can scroll down and to the right, like a spreadsheet, and it will only show the data in the current view plus minus a handle.

Now, let's also say that it takes approximately 10ms to "fetch and display" the data in that view, with a function such as:

```
get_data(start_col, end_col, start_row, end_row);
```

This loads instantly when clicking somewhere in the scroll bar or doing a 'slight scroll' to render the necessary data. However, let's also assume that for every 'unfinished fetch event', that it takes double the time to render the necessary view data (due to memory, gc, and a few other things). So, if I scroll from left-to-right in a slow deliberate fashion, I might generate   100+ scroll events that would trigger the loading of data -- at first there's zero noticeably delay. The fetch happens in under 10ms, but soon it starts taking 20ms, and then 40ms, and now we have something like a noticeable delay, until it will reach over a second to load the necessary data. Additionally, we cannot use something like a debounce/delay, as any delay will be apparent -- the data needs to load instantly when a user clicks/scrolls to a place in the grid.

What considerations would I need to take into account and what would a sample algorithm look like to accomplish this? Here is an example of the user interaction I'd like to have on the data, assuming a 10000 x 10000 spreadsheet (though Excel can load all the data at once) -- https://gyazo.com/0772f941f43f9d14f884b7afeac9f414.

Comment: Never have more than one request in flight? When the user scrolls send a request only if there's no pending request. When you get a response for the pending request, if the scroll changed since the time you sent the last request, send a new request.

Comment: I wonder why you have not accepted the answer that was given. Could you clarify why, and what you are hoping for as an answer?

Comment: @trincot -- yes it's a great answer agreed. Someone edited my original post (see edits) where I said "I will award a bounty because this is a theoretical question..."

Comment: That does not really answer my question...

Comment: Another strategy worth considering is buffering the table data based upon the direction of the scroll.  For example, if the user is scrolling down, then not only fetch what is in the view, but also fetch, say, another 25-50 rows further down in anticipation of the user continuing to scroll down.  Additionally (and I think Yosef alludes to this) before your data view consumes the buffered data, buffer more data (so you always have 25-50 rows buffered) while the user is scrolling.  This additional data will probably add little to the overhead already involved in the round trip of the fetch...

Comment: Obviously you need to perform aycnchronous preemptive checks before you actually perform scroll event based Fetch requests one after another as they are received. When you receive a Fetch request just postpone it for like 10 or so ms before actually invoking it to see if you have another Fetch request has arrived.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should not send a request at any scroll event. only if by this scroll the user reach the end of the scroll.

```
if(e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.offsetHeight === 0) {
    // the element reach the end of vertical scroll
}
if(e.target.scrollWidth - e.target.offsetWidth === 0) {
   // the element reach the end of horizontal scroll
}
```

You also can specify a width which will defined as close enough for fetch a new data (e.i. `e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.offsetHeight <= 150`)

Answer (score 3):

> Theory and practice:  In theory there is no difference between theory
>   and practice, but in practice there is.
>
> - Theory: everything is clear, but nothing works;
> - Practice: everything works, but nothing is clear;
> - Sometimes theory meets practice: nothing works and nothing is clear.

Sometimes the best approach is a prototype, and finding the problem interesting, I spent a little time cooking one up, although as a prototype it admittedly has many warts...

In short, the easiest solution to limit a backlog of data fetches appears to simply be setting up a **poor man's mutex** within the routine that's performing the fetching.  (In the code example below, the simulated fetch function is `simulateFetchOfData`.)  The mutex involves setting up a variable outside the function scope such that if `false`, the fetch is open for use, and if `true` the fetch is currently underway.

That is, when the user adjusts the horizontal or vertical slider to initiate a fetch of data, the function that fetches the data first checks to see if global variable `mutex` is true (ie, a fetch is already underway), and if so, simply exits. If `mutex` is not true, then it sets `mutex` to true, and then continues to perform the fetch.  And of course, at the end of the fetch function, `mutex` is set to false, such that the next user input event will then pass through the mutex check up front, and perform another fetch...

A couple of notes about the prototype.

- Within the `simulateFetchOfData` function, there is sleep(100) configured as a Promise which simulates the delay in retrieving the data.  This is sandwiched with some logging to the console.  If you remove the mutex check, you will see with the console open that while moving the sliders, many instances of `simulateFetchOfData` are initiated and put into suspense waiting on the sleep (ie, the simulated fetch of data) to resolve, whereas with the mutex check in place, only one instance is initiated at any one time.
- The sleep time can be adjusted to simulate greater network or database latency, so that you can get a feel for the user experience.  Eg, networks I'm on experience a 90ms latency for comms across the continental US.
- One other notable is that when finishing a fetch and after resetting `mutex` to false, a check is performed to determine if the horizontal and vertical scroll values are in alignment.  If not, another fetch is initiated.  This ensures that despite a number of scroll events possibly not firing due to the fetch being busy, that at minimum the final scroll values are addressed by triggering one final fetch.
- The simulated cell data is simply a string value of row-dash-column number.  Eg, "555-333" indicates row 555 column 333.
- A sparse array named `buffer` is used to hold the "fetched" data.  Examining it in the console will reveal many "empty x XXXX" entries.  The `simulateFetchOfData` function is set up such that if the data already is held in `buffer`, then no "fetch" is performed.

(To view the prototype, simply copy and paste the entire code into a new text file, rename to ".html", and open in a browser.  **EDIT:**  Has been tested on Chrome and Edge.)

```
<html><head>

<script>

function initialize() {

  window.rowCount = 10000;
  window.colCount = 5000;

  window.buffer = [];

  window.rowHeight = Array( rowCount ).fill( 25 );  // 20px high rows 
  window.colWidth = Array( colCount ).fill( 70 );  // 70px wide columns 

  var cellAreaCells = { row: 0, col: 0, height: 0, width: 0 };

  window.contentGridCss = [ ...document.styleSheets[ 0 ].rules ].find( rule => rule.selectorText === '.content-grid' );

  window.cellArea = document.getElementById( 'cells' );

  // Horizontal slider will indicate the left most column.
  window.hslider = document.getElementById( 'hslider' );
  hslider.min = 0;
  hslider.max = colCount;
  hslider.oninput = ( event ) => {
    updateCells();
  }

  // Vertical slider will indicate the top most row.
  window.vslider = document.getElementById( 'vslider' );
  vslider.max = 0;
  vslider.min = -rowCount;
  vslider.oninput = ( event ) => {
    updateCells();
  }

  function updateCells() {
    // Force a recalc of the cell height and width...
    simulateFetchOfData( cellArea, cellAreaCells, { row: -parseInt( vslider.value ), col: parseInt( hslider.value ) } );
  }

  window.mutex = false;
  window.lastSkippedRange = null;

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', () => {
    //cellAreaCells.height = 0;
    //cellAreaCells.width = 0;
    cellArea.innerHTML = '';
    contentGridCss.style[ "grid-template-rows" ] = "0px";
    contentGridCss.style[ "grid-template-columns" ] = "0px";

    window.initCellAreaSize = { height: document.getElementById( 'cellContainer' ).clientHeight, width: document.getElementById( 'cellContainer' ).clientWidth };
    updateCells();
  } );
  window.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'resize' ) );

}

function sleep( ms ) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout( resolve, ms ));
}

async function simulateFetchOfData( cellArea, curRange, newRange ) {

  //
  // Global var "mutex" is true if this routine is underway.
  // If so, subsequent calls from the sliders will be ignored
  // until the current process is complete.  Also, if the process
  // is underway, capture the last skipped call so that when the
  // current finishes, we can ensure that the cells align with the
  // settled scroll values.
  //
  if ( window.mutex ) {
    lastSkippedRange = newRange;
    return;
  }
  window.mutex = true;
  //
  // The cellArea width and height in pixels will tell us how much
  // room we have to fill.
  //
  // row and col is target top/left cell in the cellArea...
  //

  newRange.height = 0;
  let rowPixelTotal = 0;
  while ( newRange.row + newRange.height < rowCount && rowPixelTotal < initCellAreaSize.height ) {
    rowPixelTotal += rowHeight[ newRange.row + newRange.height ];
    newRange.height++;
  }

  newRange.width = 0;
  let colPixelTotal = 0;
  while ( newRange.col + newRange.width < colCount && colPixelTotal < initCellAreaSize.width ) {
    colPixelTotal += colWidth[ newRange.col + newRange.width ];
    newRange.width++;
  }

  //
  // Now the range to acquire is newRange. First, check if this data 
  // is already available, and if not, fetch the data.
  //

  function isFilled( buffer, range ) {
    for ( let r = range.row; r < range.row + range.height; r++ ) {
      for ( let c = range.col; c < range.col + range.width; c++ ) {
        if ( buffer[ r ] == null || buffer[ r ][ c ] == null) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  if ( !isFilled( buffer, newRange ) ) {
    // fetch data!
    for ( let r = newRange.row; r < newRange.row + newRange.height; r++ ) {  
      buffer[ r ] = [];
      for ( let c = newRange.col; c < newRange.col + newRange.width; c++ ) {
        buffer[ r ][ c ] = `${r}-${c} data`;
      }
    }
    console.log( 'Before sleep' );
    await sleep(100);
    console.log( 'After sleep' );
  }

  //
  // Now that we have the data, let's load it into the cellArea.
  //

  gridRowSpec = '';
  for ( let r = newRange.row; r < newRange.row + newRange.height; r++ ) {
    gridRowSpec += rowHeight[ r ] + 'px ';
  }

  gridColumnSpec = '';
  for ( let c = newRange.col; c < newRange.col + newRange.width; c++ ) {
    gridColumnSpec += colWidth[ c ] + 'px ';
  }

  contentGridCss.style[ "grid-template-rows" ] = gridRowSpec;
  contentGridCss.style[ "grid-template-columns" ] = gridColumnSpec;

  cellArea.innerHTML = '';

  for ( let r = newRange.row; r < newRange.row + newRange.height; r++ ) {  
    for ( let c = newRange.col; c < newRange.col + newRange.width; c++ ) {
      let div = document.createElement( 'DIV' );
      div.innerText = buffer[ r ][ c ];
      cellArea.appendChild( div );
    }
  }

  //
  // Let's update the reference to the current range viewed and clear the mutex.
  //
  curRange = newRange;

  window.mutex = false;

  //
  // One final step.  Check to see if the last skipped call to perform an update
  // matches with the current scroll bars.  If not, let's align the cells with the
  // scroll values.
  //
  if ( lastSkippedRange ) {
    if ( !( lastSkippedRange.row === newRange.row && lastSkippedRange.col === newRange.col ) ) {
      lastSkippedRange = null;
      hslider.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'input' ) );
    } else {
      lastSkippedRange = null;
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style>

/*

".range-slider" adapted from... https://codepen.io/ATC-test/pen/myPNqW

See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp for alternatives.

*/

.range-slider-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.range-slider-vertical {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}

/* grid container... see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp */

.grid-container {

  display: grid;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;

  padding: 0px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-areas:
    topLeft column  topRight
    row     cells   vslider
    botLeft hslider botRight;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 95% 27px;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 95% 27px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-topLeft {
  grid-area: topLeft;
}

.grid-column {
  grid-area: column;
}

.grid-topRight {
  grid-area: topRight;
}

.grid-row {
  grid-area: row;
}

.grid-cells {
  grid-area: cells;
}

.grid-vslider {
  grid-area: vslider;
}

.grid-botLeft {
  grid-area: botLeft;
}

.grid-hslider {
  grid-area: hslider;
}

.grid-botRight {
  grid-area: botRight;
}

/* Adapted from... https://medium.com/evodeck/responsive-data-tables-with-css-grid-3c58ecf04723 */

.content-grid {
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: 0px;  /* Set later by simulateFetchOfData */
  grid-template-columns: 0px;  /* Set later by simulateFetchOfData */
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.content-grid > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
}
</style>


</head><body onload='initialize()'>

<div class='grid-container'>
  <div class='topLeft'> TL </div>
  <div class='column' id='columns'> column </div>
  <div class='topRight'> TR </div>
  <div class='row' id = 'rows'> row </div>
  <div class='cells' id='cellContainer'>
    <div class='content-grid' id='cells'>
      Cells...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='vslider'> <input id="vslider" type="range" class="range-slider-vertical" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="0"> </div>
  <div class='botLeft'> BL </div>
  <div class='hslider'> <input id="hslider" type="range" class="range-slider-horizontal" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="0"> </div>
  <div class='botRight'> BR </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Again, this is a prototype to prove out a means to limit a backlog of unnecessary data calls.  If this were to be refactored for production purposes, many areas will require addressing, including: 1) reducing the use of the global variable space; 2) adding row and column labels; 3) adding buttons to the sliders for scrolling individual rows or columns; 4) possibly buffering related data, if data calculations are required; 5) etc...

Comment: thanks for this great answer and taking the time on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that could be done. I see it as a two-level interlayer placed between the data request procedure and the user scroll event.

**1. Delay scroll event processing**

You are right, debounce is not our friend in the scroll related issues. But there is the right way to reduce the number of firings.

Use the throttled version of scroll event handler which will be invoked at most once per every fixed interval. You may use lodash throttle or implement own version [[1](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle)], [[2](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.1.1-npm-packages/lodash.throttle/index.js#L253-L272)], [[3](https://dustinpfister.github.io/2017/10/20/lodash_throttle/)]. Set 40 - 100 ms as an interval value. You will need also to set `trailing` option so that the very last scroll event be processed regardless of the timer interval.

**2. Smart data flow**

When the scroll event handler is invoked, the data request process should be initiated. As you mentioned, doing it each time a scroll event happens (even if we are done with throttling) may cause time lags. There might be some common strategies: 1) do not request the data if there is another pending request; 2) request the data no more than one time per some interval; 3) cancel previous pending request.

The first and the second approaches are no more than the debouncing and the throttling at the data flow level. Debounce could be implemented with minimal efforts with just one condition before initiating the request + one additional request in the end. But I believe that throttle is more appropriate form the UX point of view. Here you will need to provide some logic, and do not forget about `trailing` option as it should be in game.

The last approach (the request cancellation) is also UX friendly but less careful than the throttling one. You start the request anyway but throw away its result if another request had been started after this one. You also may try to [abort the request](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch) if you are using `fetch`.

In my opinion the best option would be to combine (2) and (3) strategies, so you request the data only if some fixed time interval has passed since the initiating of the previous request AND you cancel the request if another one was initiated after.

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific algorithm that answers this question, but in order to get no buildup of delay you need to ensure two things:

#### 1. No memory leaks

Be absolutely sure that nothing in your app is creating new instances of objects, classes, arrays, etc. The memory should be the same after scrolling around for 10 seconds as it is for 60 seconds, etc. You can pre-allocate data structures if you need to (including arrays), and then re-use them:

#### 2. Constant re-use of data structures

This is common in infinite scroll pages. In an infinite scroll image gallery that shows at most 30 images on screen at one time, there might actually be only 30-40 `<img>` elements that get created. These are then used and re-used as the users scrolls, so that no new HTML elements need to be created (or destroyed, and therefore garbage-collected). Instead these images get new source URLs and new positions, and the user can keep on scrolling, but (unbeknownst to them) they always see the same DOM elements over and over.

If you're using canvas, you won't be using DOM elements to display this data, but the theory is the same, its just the data structures are your own.